# 1997 Eagle Talon won't start after overheating

Tags: overheating

I have a 1997 Eagle Talon. At first I didn't notice that it was running it without coolant because my gauge does not work. While driving, the car turned off. I then noticed that it had no water in it, so I went to the closest store, bought antifreeze and put it in the car, but still the car doesn't want to turn on. What can that possibly mean? Could it be a blown engine? If so, what can I look for in the car to figure out if the engine is blown?

Comment: When you say "doesn't turn on" do you mean you turn the key and it clicks, or do you mean it cranks (whirr, whirr, whirr) but doesn't start?

Comment: it cranks and whirr whirr

Comment: The lack of coolant might be unrelated.  At this point you need to verify the very basics, meaning fuel and spark.

Comment: so the engine might still be good than I also noticed to that my spark plugs got wet a little

Comment: Wet with what?  You mean you pulled a sparkplug and the electrodes were oily, or smelled of fuel, or do you mean the outside of the plugs are wet?  Are you certain there are no coolant leaks?

Comment: the out side of the plugs where wet with a little coolant and a little oil on them

Comment: In that case you found your problem. You overheated the engine and blew your head gasket. Coolant started getting into the cylinders and flooded the spark plugs, preventing the car from starting. You *might* be able to start it if you clean them well, but if I'm not talking complete nonsense, you'll have a big job of replacing the head gasket.

Comment: ok what about when I try starting it and water shoots out the raditor